# Проверка транзакции в контроллере

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть контроллер №1, он создает запрос, который отправляет значение в другой контролер

```
    def create
    @s_transaction = STransaction.new(s_transaction_params)
    authorize @s_transaction

    respond_to do |format|
    if @s_transaction.save
    format.html { redirect_back_or_default s_transactions_url, t('Record has 
    been saved') }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @s_transaction }
    else
    format.html {
    @s_transaction.s_transaction_materials.build if 
    @s_transaction.s_transaction_materials.blank?
    @s_transaction.s_transaction_tools.build if 
    @s_transaction.s_transaction_tools.blank?
    @s_transaction.s_transaction_others.build if 
    @s_transaction.s_transaction_others.blank?
    @s_transaction.s_transaction_additionals.build if 
    @s_transaction.s_transaction_additionals.blank?
    render :new
    }
    format.json { render json: @s_transaction.errors, status: 
    :unprocessable_entity }
    end
```

В контролере №2 идет расчет

```
    def show
authorize @facility
@facility_note = FacilityNote.new(facility: @facility)
set_return_to
@return_to = get_return_to_or_default facilities_url

@additional_list = Array.new
@material_list = Array.new
@other_list = Array.new
@tool_list = Array.new

income_transactions = STransaction.in_facility(@facility).to_a

income_transactions.each { |transaction|

  transaction.s_transaction_additionals.each { |additional|
    idx = @additional_list.find_index {|obj| obj.s_additional.id == additional.s_additional.id}
    if idx.blank?
      @additional_list << additional
    else
      @additional_list[idx].s_amount += additional.s_amount
    end
  }

  transaction.s_transaction_materials.each { |material|
    idx = @material_list.find_index {|obj| obj.s_material.id == material.s_material.id}
    if idx.blank?
      @material_list << material
    else
      @material_list[idx].s_amount += material.s_amount
    end
  }

  transaction.s_transaction_others.each { |other|
    idx = @other_list.find_index {|obj| obj.s_other.id == other.s_other.id}
    if idx.blank?
      @other_list << other
    else
      @other_list[idx].s_amount += other.s_amount
    end
  }

  transaction.s_transaction_tools.each { |tool|
    @tool_list << tool
  }

}

outcome_transactions = STransaction.out_facility(@facility).to_a

outcome_transactions.each { |transaction|

  transaction.s_transaction_additionals.each { |additional|
    idx = @additional_list.find_index {|obj| obj.s_additional.id == additional.s_additional.id}
    unless idx.blank?
      @additional_list[idx].s_amount -= additional.s_amount
    end
  }

  transaction.s_transaction_materials.each { |material|
    idx = @material_list.find_index {|obj| obj.s_material.id == material.s_material.id}
    unless idx.blank?
      @material_list[idx].s_amount -= material.s_amount
    end
  }

  transaction.s_transaction_others.each { |other|
    idx = @other_list.find_index {|obj| obj.s_other.id == other.s_other.id}
    unless idx.blank?
      @other_list[idx].s_amount -= other.s_amount
    end
  }

  transaction.s_transaction_tools.each { |tool|
    idx = @tool_list.find_index {|obj| obj.s_tool.id == tool.s_tool.id}
    unless idx.blank?
      @tool_list.delete_at(idx)
    end
  }

}

@additional_list = @additional_list.reject {|o| o.s_amount == 0}
@material_list = @material_list.reject {|o| o.s_amount == 0}
@other_list = @other_list.reject {|o| o.s_amount == 0}


end
```

Вопрос, как сделать так чтобы из запроса нельзя было получить отрицательное число ? 
Я побывал делать условие в расчете самого значения

```
     transaction.s_transaction_materials.each { |material|
idx = @material_list.find_index {|obj| obj.s_material.id == material.s_material.id}
unless idx.blank?
  @material_list[idx].s_amount -= material.s_amount
  $per = 0 
if @material_list[idx].s_amount < 0 then
$per = 1
else $per 0
  end
  end
  }
```

и в контроллер №1 добавлял это

```
    if $per = 0 then
    @s_transaction.save
    else 
    @s_transaction.destroy
```

но это работает только в половине случаев, так как сначала выполняется действие в контроллере №1 и только потом идет проверка в контроллере №2, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короткий ответ на ваш вопрос - никак.

Попробую объяснить. Контроллеры работают последовательно. То есть, когда ваш первый контроллер (полагаю, что-то вроде TransactionsController) создал транзакцию, успешно сохранил ее и выполнил строку `redirect_back_or_default ...`, он полностью закончил выполнение своего экшна и не вернётся к нему, пока вы не попробуете создать новую транзакцию. Он "передал управление" второму контроллеру (FacilitiesController, видимо) в экшн `show`, который отображает текущую facility и кучу каких-то списков по ней, учитывая в том числе и вновь созданную транзакцию. На основании данных из этого экшна вы не можете принимать никаких решений в завершенном `create`, просто потому что оно давно выполнилось.

Если я всё правильно поняла, то транзакция считается невалидной и не должна быть создана, если какие-то значения расчётов отрицательны? Для того, чтобы это заработало правильно, вам нужно написать [кастомную валидацию](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations), и все расчёты перенести туда. Если валидация не прошла, то пользователь увидит на экране вполне понятную ошибку. Учитывая объём кода, лучше создать отдельный класс валидатор, а не оставлять всё в модели.

Ну и про ваши расчёты. Подумайте над ними ещё раз, там всё должно решаться подсчётом на уровне sql с помощью `GROUP BY`, а не вот таким жестоким перебором массивов. И в любом случае, этому тоже место не в контроллере, а в методе модели, или в отдельном сервис-объекте

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, теперь я хоть примерно понимаю, что мне надо делать. .-.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!